# Sort column having float values in python

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, scipy

This is my list :

```
vec = [[(0, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (1, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (2, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (3, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (4, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (5, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (6, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (7, 0.0007714083510261222),
      (8, 6.369426751591834e-05),  
      ...........................
      (4995, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (4996, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (4997, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (4998, 6.369426751591834e-05),
      (4999, 6.369426751591834e-05)]]
```

I want to sort it based 2nd column which has float value. Plus how to print first 10 from the output list.
I tried many methods, but couldn't figure out. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: try this `sorted(vec[0], key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Paulo, it was output of lda algorithm, it was nested by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(vec[0], key=lambda x: x[1])
```

vec[0] only because you have a nested list... normally it would just be vec

Comment: This is a `TypeError`; `key` must be a keyword argument

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but above one by @Grijesh worked. I tried yours, it gives :TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can sort by the `i`th value in a container using [`operator.itemgetter(i)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as the `key` for sorting:

```
from operator import itemgetter

vec[0] = sorted(vec[0], key=itemgetter(1))
```

On your example, with some duplicates removed:

```
>>> vec = [[(0, 6.369426751591834e-05),
            (7, 0.0007714083510261222),
            (8, 6.369426751591834e-05)]]
>>> sorted(vec[0], key=itemgetter(1))
[(0, 6.369426751591834e-05), 
 (8, 6.369426751591834e-05), 
 (7, 0.0007714083510261222)]
```

Comment: A little overkill. @d_rez90's is simpler

Comment: This one worked too! Thanks. I can't upvote your replies guys, i don't have enough points.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy` way of doing it:

```
In [7]:
AV=np.array(vec)
AV[:,np.argsort(AV[:,:,1])]
Out[7]:
array([[[[  0.00000000e+00,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  1.00000000e+00,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  2.00000000e+00,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  3.00000000e+00,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  4.00000000e+00,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  5.00000000e+00,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  6.00000000e+00,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  8.00000000e+00,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  4.99500000e+03,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  4.99600000e+03,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  4.99700000e+03,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  4.99800000e+03,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  4.99900000e+03,   6.36942675e-05],
         [  7.00000000e+00,   7.71408351e-04]]]])
```

There is a `np.set_printoptions()` for controlling print options. There is no way, however, to only print the first 10 lines, you can instead print the first `n` lines and the last `n` lines by: `np.set_printoptions(threshold=a_samll_number, edgeitems=n)`

Comment: Thanks, that printing option is really handy for observing first and last ten results.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked to print the first ten:

```
srtd = sorted(vec[0], lambda x: x[1])
print srtd[:10]
```

Comment: Put a minus in front of x[1] if you want to flip sort order.

Comment: I already tried vec[:10], it prints the whole list in my case

Comment: That's because your list is nested. Above will work as it takes out the first element. You would need vec[0][:10]. Or simply don't nest the list inside another list.

Comment: yes, it works after adding key: as pointed above:        sorted(vec[0], key=lambda x: x[1])

Comment: How do i un-nest the list then? because with srtd[0][:10] i only able to see single value and with srtd[:10] i can see the 10 values but that shows value of single column. The numpy method gives somewhat clean list.

Comment: When you declare it, you are declaring it with two square brackets. Use one. Then you can remove the [0] from a lot of the solutions. The numpy one works well as he is extracting the inner list first with: [:,:,1]. However, that seems a little overkill. My modification of @d_rev90's is the simplest approach.